# How to include required dll to a mvc c++ build

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dependencies

I have a project that relies on some other projects on my solution. For example assume that my main project is m and it produce m.exe

This project depends on some other projects say a.dll, b.dll,c.dll.

My problem is:

when I build m.exe, a.dll,b.dll and c.dll are created and the output is placed in some directory on my pc, but these dlls are not copied to output directory of m.exe and hence when I want to debug m.exe, they are not found.

If I copied them to output directory (debug directory) the application runs, but I am not able to debug into a.dll,b.dll and c.dll.

How can setup my MSVC so I can compile and debug into these dlls?

I am using Visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project settings (Configuration Settings -> General) for each project, you can set the output directory. Change it for every configuration/platform of every project to e.g. `$(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\` (or anything else that resolves to the same location for each project).

The alternatives are to either add a post-build step to copy files around via command, or to change your DLL resolution mechanism and use delay loading code that resolves referenced DLLs "manually".